# Error while generating pdf from Html file in Java using iText

Tags: java, itext

I am converting XML -> HTML -> pdf. The HTML -> pdf step is done with iText v5.5.3, but I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable.addCell(Lcom/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPCell;)V
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.table.Table.end(Table.java:387)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.AbstractTagProcessor.endElement(AbstractTagProcessor.java:155)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline.close(HtmlPipeline.java:202)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.endElement(XMLWorker.java:140)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.endElement(XMLParser.java:387)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.ClosingTagState.process(ClosingTagState.java:70)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:230)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:209)
    at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:166)
    at ITextEx.createPdf(ITextEx.java:29)
    at ITextEx.main(ITextEx.java:41)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It says java.lang.NoSuchMethodError. Maybe you try to call a method that does not exsist?

Comment: maybe a version mismatch between your jar files.

Comment: Which iText jar files (name and version) are in your classpath?

Comment: I am using itextpdf-5.5.3.jar.

Comment: You need xmlworker-5.5.3.jar as well.

Comment: It worked! Earlier I was using xmlworker of some different version!
Thanks @KlasLindbäck

Comment: I have one more question.. I converted first xml -> html.
But when I tried to convert html to pdf it asked me to give the closing tag for <hr> which I had to give manually. Then conversion to pdf worked! But I don't want to add any tag manually. How to do it?

Comment: `<hr>` and `<br>` are a bit tricky, because they don't require a closing tag in html (but they do in xhtml). If you can get the xml -> html conversion to generate closed tags (`<hr />` instead of `<hr>`) the html -> pdf conversion should work nicely.

Comment: @KannuVerma Please post your comment as a question and I will give you an answer so that you don't need to change those tags manually.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Please answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652029/how-to-do-xml-to-html-conversion-to-generate-closed-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html -> pdf conversion functionality is in a separate jar file, `xmlworker-<version>.jar`, but is still considered part of iText.

If you are using `itextpdf-5.5.3.jar` you should use `xmlworker-5.5.3.jar`.

Xmlworker is a part of the iText product and can be downloaded from the product web site.

Comment: I was just going to ask you to post your comment as an answer, so that I could upvote it ;-)