# How to do HTML to XML conversion to generate closed tags?

Tags: html, xml, itext

How to do xml to html conversion to generate closed tags.

The context is explained here: [Error while generating pdf from Html file in Java using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648853/error-while-generating-pdf-from-html-file-in-java-using-itext)

When I try converting html to pdf using iText and XML Worker, I'm asked to give the closing tag for `<hr>` and `<br>` tags. It works if I do this manually: conversion to pdf worked! But I don't want to add each closing tag manually. How can I do this in an automated way?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No need to downvote, this is the short version of a question that appeared here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648853/error-while-generating-pdf-from-html-file-in-java-using-itext

Comment: I regret my upvote. I wanted to use this question as a duplicate, but I see that @KannuVerma didn't have the decency to accept my correct answer so I can't use it as a reference in a close vote.

Comment: @brunoLowagie I did not try this solution because it was no longer needed for me. Your solution may be working well but if someone forget to put comment, it does not make them indecent!

Comment: OK, but you posted your question on Oct 30 '14 at 11:40 and I provided you with an answer on the same day at 12:09. The least you could have done was to provide some feedback. My response time was less than half an hour! You are now saying that you found another solution in less than half an hour. If it took you only that long to find a solution, why did you even bother asking the question? That doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: I did not say I found another solution. I said 'It was no longer needed for me'!! Anyway I don't want to continue the discussion about something which happened last year. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

You are experiencing this problem because you are feeding HTML to iText's XML Worker. XML Worker requires XML, so you need to convert your HTML into XHTML.

There is an example on how to do this on the official iText site: [D00_XHTML](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/D00_XHTML)

```
public static void tidyUp(String path) throws IOException {
    File html = new File(path);
    byte[] xhtml = Jsoup.parse(html, "US-ASCII").html().getBytes();
    File dir = new File("results/xml");
    dir.mkdirs();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, html.getName()));
    fos.write(xhtml);
    fos.close();
}
```

In this example, we get a path to an ordinary HTML file (similar to what you have). We then use the [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library to parse the HTML into an XHTML byte array. In this example, we use that byte array to write an XHTML file to disk. You can use the byte array directly as input for XML Worker.