# What is clean <span /> free html tag Regex or other ways?

Tags: html, regex, itext

```
<div style="font-size:20px;font-family:arial;x:5;color:red;">Test</div><span/>
```

`<span />` it's blank and PDF exception because.

```
var elements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(reader, style, null);
```

[image]

Comment: span has an opening and closing tag and the slash is in the wrong place `<span></span>` whats creating the html ?

Comment: I know <span></span> correct. but html code auto generated by ckeditor. 

I need this tags clean..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment, you say that you know that `<span></span>` is correct, but that you are faced with existing  tags.

In my comment, I referred to my answer to this question: [How to do HTML to XML conversion to generate closed tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652029/how-to-do-xml-to-html-conversion-to-generate-closed-tags)

In this question, I explain that it is good practice to run "bad HTML" through jsoup before feeding the HTML to XML Worker. I have used the code in the [D00_HTML](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/D00_XHTML) example on your snippet.

This:

```
<div style="font-size:20px;font-family:arial;x:5;color:red;">Test</div><span/>
```

was converted into this:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div style="font-size:20px;font-family:arial;x:5;color:red;">
   Test
  </div>
  <span></span>
 </body>
</html>
```

using this code:

```
public static void tidyUp(String path) throws IOException {
    File html = new File(path);
    byte[] xhtml = Jsoup.parse(html, "US-ASCII").html().getBytes();
    File dir = new File("results/xml");
    dir.mkdirs();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, html.getName()));
    fos.write(xhtml);
    fos.close();
}
```

I also want to inform you that it is not a good idea to use `HTMLWorker`. That class has been abandoned and is no longer be supported. It will probably be removed in one of the future releases. You should use XML Worker instead. You can find XML Worker examples on [the itext site](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker) as well as in the book [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) (this book is free, so you might want to download it. the question with the answer to your question was selected as one of the best questions).

Answer (score 1):

span has an opening and closing tag and the slash is in the wrong place  the error is saying that if found something other than an angle bracket,

```
 <span [HERE] >
```

you currently have

```
<span />
```

Comment: I have database html texts(ckeditor output) , so clean endwith /> tags.