# Invalid nested tag div found, expected closing tag script exception in itextsharp XMLWorkerHelper

Tags: c#, html, itext, sharepoint-2013

I am converting sharepoint aspx page content to pdf using the below code but while parsing the htmlstring its throwing this error: "Invalid nested tag div found, expected closing tag script" How can I handle this kind of invalid tag or tag closing issue thru the C# code, so that I can pass the valid htmlString to the method.

```
//Create a byte array that will eventually hold our final PDF
Byte[] bytes;
//Boilerplate iTextSharp setup here
//Create a stream that we can write to, in this case a MemoryStream
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    //Create an iTextSharp Document which is an abstraction of a PDF but **NOT** a PDF
    using (var doc = new Document()) {
        //Create a writer that's bound to our PDF abstraction and our stream
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)) {
            //Open the document for writing
            doc.Open();

            //Our sample HTML
            var example_html = GetHtmlSource(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString());                  
            using (var srHtml = new StringReader(example_html)) {
                //Parse the HTML
                iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);   **In this line throwing exception**
            }                                         
        } 
        doc.Close();
    }
}    
bytes = ms.ToArray();
```

Comment: Posting your `html` would be helpful

Comment: I wanted to close this question because it's a duplicate of [How to do HTML to XML conversion to generate closed
tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652029/how-to-do-xml-to-html-conversion-to-generate-closed-tags) but I can't because my correct answer was never accepted. XML Worker parses XHTML and you're giving it dirty HTML with tags that are opened and never closed. Please browse [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) before asking a question that was answered before.